# Can you limit the scope of the destination expression when using an SSRS LookupSet based on the category in a chart?

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart which shows the total number of calls received in a contact centre over time. The report user chooses how to group the chart by selecting a parameter “rangeView” which has the options: “D” (Day), “W” (Week), “M” (Month). The user also chooses the date range “StartDate” and “EndDate” which gets passed to the stored proc to retrieve the data.

The dataset “BusyHourStats” contains a row for every hour of each day in the date range and has the following columns:

- LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24 (the hour of the day eg: “2018-01-01 14”)
- LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD (day eg: “2018-01-01”)
- LABEL_YYYY_WE (week eg: “2018-W01)
- LABEL_YYYY_MM (month eg: “2018-01”)
- TOTAL_CALLS

The chart series is Sum(TOTAL_CALLS).

The chart Category Group expression uses the rangeView parameter:

```
=Switch(Parameters!rangeView.Value = "D", Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD.Value,
    Parameters!rangeView.Value = "W", Fields!LABEL_YYYY_WE.Value,
    Parameters!rangeView.Value = "M", Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM
)
```

This works as expected, grouping the results by Day, Week or Month. No problems with displaying the data in the chart.

Problem:

As a Series tooltip when you hover over the category (which could be a day, week or month) I need to display Max(TOTAL_CALLS.Value) and the day and hour (or days and hours) when that the max total calls occurred. Eg: “Busy hour: 159 calls on 2018-01-03 14, 2018-01-05 16.”

I have been trying to use LookupSet but I’m not sure if this is the best way to go about it. Should a LookupSet be used when the source and destination dataset is the same dataset or is there a smarter/simpler way? My problem as best I understand is that the lookup finds the Max(TOTAL_CALLS.Value) in the source dataset and then matches it on and returns all TOTAL_CALLS.Values in the entire destination dataset (which includes all the data between the StartDate and EndDate). What I need is to have the lookup only match on the values that align with the category (day, week or month) which is being hovered over.

Is there are way to limit the scope of the destination expression in the lookup based on the current category being hovered over in the chart?

What I have got so far in the Series tooltip is (simplified for this example):

```
="Busy hour: " & Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value) & "calls on " & 
Join(LookupSet(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value), 
    Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value, 
    Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24.Value), 
    "BusyHourStats"), ", ")
```

which returns all the matching TOTAL_CALLS values in the dataset. What I need to work out is how to do something that equates to:

```
="Busy hour: " & Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value) & "calls on " & 
Join(LookupSet(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value), 
    Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value *<where scope equals the category being hovered over such as “2018 01” or “2018-W01”>*, 
    Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24.Value), 
    "BusyHourStats"), ", ")
```

I’m not sure if I am wasting my time trying to get the results I need by using LookupSet. Is there a more appropriate function/method I should be using or can it be done this way?

Edit: Attaching image. I have also provided the exact tooltip expression below which aligns with the tooltip shown in the image:

```
=Switch(
    Parameters!rangeView.Value = "D", "Date: " & Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value & Switch(
        (Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 1 or Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 21 or Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 31), "st ",
        (Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 2 or Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 22), "nd ",
        (Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 3 or Fields!CAL_DAY_NUM_IN_MONTH.Value = 23), "rd ",
        1=1, "th "
    ) & Fields!CAL_MONTH_NAME.Value & " " &Fields!LABEL_YYYY.Value,
    Parameters!rangeView.Value = "W", "Week: " & Fields!LABEL_YYYY_WE.Value,
    Parameters!rangeView.Value = "M", "Month: " & Fields!CAL_MONTH_NAME.Value & " " & Fields!LABEL_YYYY.Value
) &
vbcrlf &
"Total Volume: " & FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value),0) & IIF(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value) = 1, " call", " calls") &
vbcrlf &
"Busy hour: " & FormatNumber(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value),0) & IIF(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value) = 1, " call at ", " calls at ") & 
Join(LookupSet(Max(Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value), 
    Fields!TOTAL_CALLS.Value, 
    Fields!HourTime.Value & IIF(Parameters!rangeView.Value = "D", Nothing, " on " & Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD.Value), 
    "BusyHourStats"), Environment.NewLine & "                               and ") &
vbcrlf &
"Max Concurrent: " & FormatNumber(Max(Fields!MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS.Value),0) & IIF(Max(Fields!MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS.Value) = 1, " call at ", " calls at ") & 
Join(LookupSet(Max(Fields!MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS.Value), 
    Fields!MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS.Value, 
    Fields!HourTime.Value & IIF(Parameters!rangeView.Value = "D", Nothing, " on " & Fields!LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD.Value), 
    "BusyHourStats"), Environment.NewLine & "                                        and ")
```

As you can see when I hover the mouse over the category month "January 2018" it is returning the correct matching value for January "11am on 2018-01-12" but it is also returning the matching value for February "3pm on 2018-02-15". I'd like to only get the matches for the Month that is being hovered over (or Day or Week being hovered over depending on the category grouping chosen when the report was run).

Image:[Report showing tooltip for January](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ckI.jpg)

Edit2: Added sample dataset below (csv). Note: removed many rows to comply to character limit in this post. The sample is exactly as used in the report (which is slightly different to the original post description).

```
BUSINESS_UNIT,CAL_MONTH_NAME,LABEL_WE,CAL_WEEK_START_DATE,CAL_WEEK_END_DATE,LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD,LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24,TOTAL_CALLS,MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 11,85,3
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 12,16,2
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 13,3,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 14,8,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 15,9,2
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 16,9,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-12,2018-01-12 19,1,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-13,2018-01-13 09,1,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-13,2018-01-13 11,2,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-13,2018-01-13 12,1,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-13,2018-01-13 13,2,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-13,2018-01-13 14,1,1
    <All>,January,W02,2018-01-08 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14 00:00:00.000,2018-01-14,2018-01-14 10,5,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 06,1,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 07,12,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 08,11,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 09,24,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 10,6,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 11,19,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 12,4,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 13,38,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 14,49,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 15,28,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 16,28,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-15,2018-01-15 21,1,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 07,5,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 08,23,1
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 09,27,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 10,77,4
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 11,19,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 12,14,3
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 13,43,2
    <All>,January,W03,2018-01-15 00:00:00.000,2018-01-21 00:00:00.000,2018-01-16,2018-01-16 14,37,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-13,2018-02-13 20,2,5
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 07,165,50
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 08,5,7
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 09,365,51
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 10,11,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 11,58,3
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 12,9,1
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 13,425,53
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 14,79,4
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 15,57,4
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 16,16,3
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 17,13,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 18,1,1
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-14,2018-02-14 21,1,1
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 07,5,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 08,17,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 09,4,1
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 10,30,3
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 11,42,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 12,17,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 13,37,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 14,62,3
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 15,85,3
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 16,33,2
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 18,1,1
    <All>,February,W07,2018-02-12 00:00:00.000,2018-02-18 00:00:00.000,2018-02-15,2018-02-15 22,6,1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, maybe a sample set of data and expected output would help... Having said that, if you expression more or less works you could try just changing the scope from "BusyHourStats" to the name of the category group. I'm not sure this will work in a chart but worth a go. The other option may be to add the data as an extra column in the SQL dataset and then just use that for the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alan. I tried replacing the "BusyHourStats" with the name of the category group "Chart12_CategoryGroup" however I get the following error: _"The ToolTip expression for the chart ‘Chart12’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset. (rsInvalidLookupScope)"_. I will try to provide a sample set of data.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the tooltip output. Am I able to upload a sample data set as a csv file?

Comment: You can limit a scope in the expression for example with a grouping `Max(Fields!TestField.Value, "MonthGrouping")` or the whole dataset `Max(Fields!TestField.Value, "DataSet1")`. You can also check for a scope with the expression `InScope(Fields!TestField.Value)`. Maybe one of this two will help you.

Comment: Personally, I would do a lot of this on the server and let SSRS have an easier time :) 
I did a quick bit of t-sql to demo which you could use as your dataset. It only handle the max calls but its easy to extend to cover concurrent in the same way. I also changed one record so there are two with 85 total calls just so I got varied results. If updating the dataset query is possible then have a look at this saved query, (run it) it has additional columns with the busy hours for month, week and day level. It will need some tidying up but hopefully will be useful https://rextester.com/SEO17421

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield. This is a good solution. I was unsure how I would go about adding the max values to the dataset but your query has given me something to think about. I will now go and learn about the "stuff" and "xml" part of the cte's so that I understand it properly and then update the dataset stored proc so that the busy hours are ready to call as needed. Thanks again. and thanks to you too Strawberryshrub.

Comment: No problem zipzip, xml path and stuff can be very useful in situations like this. They can also appear a little confusing at first but actually, once you look at a few examples they are pretty straight forward. Good luck